# Magento 1.9 - Change Tax in created invoice

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, invoice, tax, sql

Unfortunately somebody changed the tax class for many of our products.
We needed 2 weeks to recognize that. Now I got 150 orders with wrong tax.
I need to fix that and resend all invoices to the customers.
I tried to check the SQL for the right entrys and fix it manually but I failed in that jungle.
Maybe somebody got any script for things like that? Or could me please say in wich tables i got to fix that manualy?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The tax calculation process is not quite simple in Magento therefore I'm not sure if there is a posibility to create an appropriate statement.

But if you can calculate the tax amounts for your products you can update the following tables (just look for the columns containing `tax` which have values for your 150 orders):

```
sales_flat_order
sales_flat_order_item
sales_flat_invoice
sales_flat_invoice_item
sales_order_tax
sales_order_tax_item
```

If the total amounts of the orders are also afected by your tax class changes you have to updated the corresponding columns to and also the grid tables:

```
sales_flat_order_grid
sales_flat_invoice_grid
```

I hope that helps.